# Reactjs table row button click not working

Tags: reactjs

Why in the following code `Delete` button click does not hit the `delete` method? What i am missing important thing? I am new to learn React.js

```
delete(e) {
    console.log('Deleted');
}

static renderCatTable(Categories) {
    return (
        <table className='table table-striped'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th></th>

                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {Categories.map(category =>
                    <tr key={category._id}>
                        <td>{category.code}</td>
                        <td><button onClick={this.delete} className="btn btn-danger">Delete</button></td>                        
                    </tr>

                )}
            </tbody>
        </table>
    );
}
```

I have defined the binding inside the constructor

```
this.delete = this.delete.bind(this);
```

The render function is given below.

```
render() {
    let contents = this.state.loading
        ? <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        : Category.renderCatTable(this.state.Categories);
    return (
        <div>         
            {contents}
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because that render method is `static`. By definition, `static` methods cannot access an instance variable. You should remove that modifier if possible and it should work.